# How to extract IBAN number using emv payment method

Tags: emv, iban

I am trying to read the IBAN from a contactless card and I am using the PAN/Track 2 equivalent data tag, but I can see that the bank code is 5 digits (institute number), not 8. I don't know how to find or convert that to blz. I can't find anywhere this blz number in the records of the card.

Answer (score 0):

5 Digits it could be the BIN. https://www.bindb.com/bin-database.html

But the EMV Standard doesn't define how the PAN looks in detail, so it could be different for a card from a different country.

Answer (score 0):

IBAN is expected in tag 5F53.
Bank code, BIN was 6 digit all these years, but now payment schemes are coming up with plan to make BIN 8 digit and strictly enforcing account range (first 9) so as to reduce numeric wastage. It was never 5. 
You can take BIN from track 2 data in tag 57.
What is blz?

Comment: @arved I don't think that this number that I am parsing is BIN and also in none of the scanned cards there was 5F53 tag, I will give you more information: The IBAN that is stored in the card looks like this: DEXX 50050201 XXXXXXXXXX. The PAN that I am reading looks like this: 67 255002 XXXXXXXXXX 1F. The BLZ (bank identification code for German banks) is 50050201 and I need to somehow get it from 255002

Comment: hi @Kristina you need to split your comments on arved's answer under that post itself to reduce confusions later. Have you checked for 5F53 in FCI Issuer Discretionary Data ? I have worked on IBAN generation, however the presence of same in card is comparatively less, maybe since as you can always change the account mapping at host. As I said before, payment schemes are migrating  to 8 digit bins gradually.

Comment: Kristina, as it seems to be your dealing with German Cards, here is an Article in the German Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_Account_Number which explains the format and has some further links.

Comment: @arved Yes, that is exactly the format but I can't match it to the IBAN, went through all the records in the card and found no data for the bank code.